# Link C++Builder application without requiring any DLL's?

Tags: c++builder

I moved to the **release** build to get an idea of the size of the `.exe` and wanted to ensure it was a standalone `.exe`, so I check that **Link with runtime packages** was `False` and that **Link with Dynamic RTL** was also `False` and they are (as well as **Link with the Delphi Runtime Library**), but when I use **Project/Deployment** it tells me, besides the `.exe` itself, I'll need:

```
cc32c280mt.dll
cc32c280.dll
cc32280.dll
borlndmm.dll
cc32280mt.dll
```

How do I prevent that?

Also, does 18MB to 20MB seem in line with C++Builder SQLite/FireDac applications?

P.S. I use the **modern clang C++ compiler**.

[image]

Comment: It looks like "Link with Dynamic RTL" was `true`. Did you perhaps only set it to `false` in the debug configuration?

Comment: @TedLyngmo updated to include pic.  Also if I changed the "Link with runtime packages" the list of things required is huge.

Comment: The image shows that you set the proper items in the Release configuration, but did you actually do a Release build (make the Release target the active one and do a project build rather than just a compile)?

Comment: make sure to full rebuild of everything after changing the setings

Comment: Sidenote: Are you still releasing 32 bit apps? I didn't think anyone used 32 bit Windowses anymore.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, I forced a full build and release is target and output went to release directory.  Unless the "project / deployment" is giving me the wrong information?  It says its showing for the release as well.

Comment: @TedLyngmo both, only because this product has one that requires matching the os.  C++Builder seemed to only add 64bit recently, win32 runs on both for normal apps so presume that's why it's the primary version.  I couldn't build x64 because some libraries provided were incorrect, but will have to at some point because need both.

Comment: Maybe the "Project/Deployment" is not telling the truth?  Is it using AI?  I was able to run it on an alternate machine which I'm sure doesn't have those libraries.  I didn't test every facet of the app but it ran ?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Making 32bit apps is still very common, as most apps don't need access to 64bits worth of memory.

Comment: @user3161924 "*C++Builder seemed to only add 64bit recently*" - C++Builder has supported 64bit Windows development since 2013. "*Maybe the "Project/Deployment" is not telling the truth?*" - maybe, maybe not. It might just be deploying a default set of files regardless of what the exe actually depends on. There are 3rd party dependancy tools you can run on the exe itself to see what it really depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps are needed for static linking:

- Disable *Building -> C++ linker -> Link with dynamic RTL*
- Disable *Packages -> Runtime packages -> Link with runtime packages*

You did both, so your program shouldn't need any DLLs.

*Project -> Deployment* is simply incorrect. For example in a project I am developing it lists all `.c` files, even though they are certainly compiled and linked with the project.